# How to package shared objects that python modules depend on?

Tags: c++, python, boost-python

I have a python package implemented in C++ that I am distributing using setuptools. My C++ code depends on some shared objects, specifically the boost.python library. How should I distribute these shared objects? At the moment I ask the package user to install the boost C++ libraries separately but I would rather bundle everything in one setuptools distribution to make it easier for him/her. At the moment they must set up the boost libraries and their `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable in addition to installing my package.

Comment: Have you tried linking your dependencies statically into your Python shared object? Of course you would need to obtain static libraries of your dependencies for that.

Comment: I did think of that but for various technical reasons it is necessary to share the boost.python library between modules.

Answer (score 0):

### Declaring dependencies

There is an option in  `setup.py` called `install_requires = [""]` :
Ex :

```
setup(
    name='django-cherrypy',
    version='0.1',
    packages=packages,
    license='LICENSE',
    description='cherrypy, running under django',
    long_description=open('README.md').read(),
    author='Calvin Cheng',
    author_email='calvin@calvinx.com',
    install_requires=['cherrypy-wsgiserver'],
    extra_requires=['newrelic'],
    url='https://github.com/od-eon/django-cherrypy',
)
```

This setup ask for chrerryPy WSGI server library.

### Bundle Everything

Everything is explained here : http://pythonhosted.org/distribute/setuptools.html#declaring-dependencies

> Depedencies in PiPy :
>
> 1. When your project is installed, either by using EasyInstall,
>      setup.py install, or setup.py develop, all of the dependencies not
>      already installed will be located (via PyPI), downloaded, built (if
>      necessary), and installed.
> 2. Any scripts in your project will be
>      installed with wrappers that verify the availability of the
>      specified dependencies at runtime, and ensure that the correct
>      versions are added to sys.path (e.g. if multiple versions have been
>      installed).
> 3. Python Egg distributions will include a metadata file
>      listing the dependencies
>
> Dependencies that aren’t in PyPI
>
> If your project depends on packages that aren’t registered in PyPI,
>   you may still be able to depend on them, as long as they are available
>   for download as:
>
> - an egg, in the standard distutils sdist format,
> - a single .py file,
> - or a VCS repository (Subversion, Mercurial, or Git).  You just need to add some URLs to the dependency_links argument to setup().

Comment: My dependency is a shared object I can build from C++ code not another python package. I guess I really need distribute/setuptools/whatever to build my shared object (as it does my extension module) and install it somewhere sensible. Is there any facility to do this?

Comment: bundle a handmade build script with these operations automated (batch, bjam, cmake, etc..) . But, in the Boost.Python case, you don't need to install it, just link the headers, right ?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "link the headers" but at runtime my python extension is going to look for a boost.python shared object which had better be somewhere. Perhaps by "link the headers" you mean put the headers somewhere and compile boost.python statically obviating the need to find the boost.python shared object at runtime. That could work but would eliminate the possibility of sharing the boost.python registry across different python extensions. Bundling a handmade script sounds promising. How do I tell setuptools about it? Where will setuptools put the shared object?