# Creating a Python package depending on Boost

Tags: c++, python-3.x, pypi, boost-python, python-packaging

I'm looking to distribute a Python package that depends on Boost Python, but I'm not sure how to configure the setup.

In the current state, the setup requires the path to the Boost `.so` to be manually set before running the setup script (example for Python3.7 on Ubuntu commented on the side)

```py
module = setuptools.Extension(
    # ... 
    include_dirs=['path/to/python/version'], # /usr/include/python3.7/
    libraries=['boost-so-filename'], # boost_python-py37
    library_dirs=['directory/containing/boost/so/'], # /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
    # ...
)

setup(
    # ...,
    ext_modules=[module]
    # ...,
)
```

How can I configure setup to be able to support any Python version `>=3.7`, know where Boost is, and link to the corresponding Boost version for their Python version?

[Python packaging: Boost library as dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46824239) suggests using a binary wheel, but I don't think that would necessarily work for supporting multiple versions, and either way I'm not entirely sure how to approach it

A comment in [How to package shared objects that python modules depend on?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17484752) mentions something about having a build script handling this, but it's not elaborated upon.